# Wine no longer letting me play SC2 or launch Bnet browser

Tags: starcraft-2, linux, wine

I've been playing SC2 and Heroes of the Storm fine on Wine for awhile now but suddenly today it will no longer launch I've tried restarting and Google and so forth but nothing has worked. Has anyone else had this problem?

The error I get is:
"The program Battle.net.exe has encountered a serious 
problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the 
inconvenience.

This can be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in 
Wine. You may want to check http://appdb.winehq.org for tips about 
running this application." and the same but with "BlizzardError.exe" at the same time.

Here is the detail list it gives me for the Battle.net.exe error: 
http://pastebin.com/gAEHrr1e

If anyone could please help it would be extremely appreciated. I'd hate to have to reformat.

Comment: This question is an exact copy of the question asked by @scarecrow on the same day, including the broken pastebin link. It appears clear from the rep on each account that this account was created by scarecrow to double post this question. Flagging for removal.